# What is this mathematical expression?

Tags: summation

I am trying to figure out what the attached picture's mathematical expressions mean. We have a kernel function $k$ that takes in 2 vectors that are $\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I don't understand what the subscripts in the sum mean, could someone explain? What do the $j_1,...,j_d$ stand for? I also do not understand what the big parenthesis means. Could someone explain this to me as well?

[image: Referenced picture]

Comment: This may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time searching because I did not know what the name of this expression is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $j_1, \ldots, j_d$ are nonnegative and sum to $p$.

and $$\binom{p}{j_1, \ldots, j_d} = \frac{p!}{j_1! j_2! \ldots j_d!}=\frac{p!}{\prod_{i=1}^d j_i!}$$

The multinomial coefficient.

Note that $$(u^Tv)^p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^d u^{(i)}v^{(i)} \right)^p$$

Comment: Why does the sum subscripts mean the j's are non-negative?

Comment: it didn't say that explicitly, but since I know the multinomial theorem...

Comment: Ohh. So does $j_1,\ldots,j_d$ take on the values of $1,\ldots,d$, respecitlvey?

Comment: they have to sum up to $p$, so nope.

Comment: for example if $d=3$, and $p=5$, some of the indices are $(5, 0,0), (1,2,2)$, $(3,0,2)$, and so on.

Comment: Ah okay. And is there a typo in your last edit? There shouldn't be a p on the RHS, or the LHS is missing a p.

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Comment: One more question. You gave the example for $d=3$ and $p=5$. So $j_1,\ldots,j_d$ the set of all indices that satisfy $j_1 + \ldots + j_d = p$?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Is there a quick way to modify the multinomial expression for $(u^Tv)^p$ to $(u^Tv+1)^p$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85160/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-iamanon).